# Where does Edge store user's virtualized files?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm trying to locate a log file created by a CSP that under IE11 is stored in  DRIVE:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized...

Where are users' temporary files created when using the Edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 10 installed on this machine to look for the exact location, but it should be somewhere in this directory:

```
%LocalAppData%\Spartan
```

If they've already switched folder names to Edge, then just replace instances of `Spartan` as necessary. You may need to un-hide hidden folders if you haven't already changed that setting.